# Failed to load resource 404

Tags: page-layout

Knowing nothing about sharepoint, I inadvertently moved a source file, that was used as our logo on our home page.  Now the logo will not load.   I want to restore our logo but don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Open Site Settings and there you can see the option to change site Logo.

- On the right, click the gear icon and then click Site Settings
- Under Look and Feel click Title, Description, and Logo
- Under Insert Logo, place the URL of your logo and click OK

Comment: Thank you Amal, but what and where on the Site Settings page will I find that option.  Tab

Comment: You can use the Look and Feel link

Comment: Yes, under the "Look and Feel" link, I have Quick Launch and Top Link Bar, neither take me to where I can change the logo.

Comment: Try enabling Publishing feature from Site Collection Feature List